# How to set the previously used password for users in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Salesforce is not allowing me to set the previously used password. It throwing exception like "Invalid- Repeat Password"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce not allowing to use your old password.It is because in your ORG there is Password Policy to remember the old password to make sure old password is not used again.

To Set the Old Password again :- Open "Password Policies" search from quick box.
You will find "Enforce password history" field.

if "Enforce password history" field is set for "8 password remembered".

then you have to change password maximum 8 times with other values so the old password gets removed from the database and you can able to retain your previous password.